# Can't see my user controls in a foreach

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I can't seem to find my custom user controls during a for-each.

It is a custom user control, and here is my code:

```
            <uc2:MetaTag runat="server" id="MetaTag" SystemCode="TEXT" Text="test" />
```

But it does find the literal control that I have.

```
        foreach (Control controlItemFound in Page.Controls)
        {
            Response.Write("Control Found: " + controlItemFound.GetType() + "<br );
            if(controlItemFound is MetaTag)
            {
                MetaTag ctrl = (MetaTag)controlItemFound;

                ctrl.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("MetaTag FOUND!!!");
            }
            if (controlItemFound is LiteralControl)
            {
                LiteralControl ctrl = (LiteralControl)controlItemFound;

                ctrl.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("Server Text!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page.Controls will only give you access to the controls directly in the page Class. It doesn't include controls nested within other controls.
For instance the Literal and Meta controls you may have added to the Page (nested in the Form tag) would not be included in the Page.Controls collection.

As for the LiteralControl you have identified in the Page.Controls collection, this would be one of the LiteralControls added by the ASP.NET framework.

Try iterating through the Controls property of the container of the Meta controls.
If the Meta control is a direct child of the Form (Form tag),

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc2:metatag runat="server" id="MetaTag" systemcode="TEXT" text="test" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then use the following code, where form1 is the name of Form

```
foreach (Control controlItemFound in this.form1.Controls)
{
}
```